# How to read a list from stdin of arbitrary type [a] in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, types, io, functional-programming, io-monad

I'm writing a function that takes arbitrary lists and compares them to see if one is a sublist of the other. For stdin, I wanted to ask the user for two lists but I can't figure out a way to accept an arbitrary type. Here is my code so far:

```
1  main :: IO ()
2  main = do
3      l1 <- getLine
4      l2 <- getLine
5      print $ sublist (read l1 :: [Int]) (read l2:: [Int])
6  
7  sublist :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
8  sublist b p = any ((b ==) . take len) . takeWhile ((len<=) . length) $ iterate tail p
9      where len = length b
```

My main issue is line `5` where I have to pick a type for `read`.

Some examples of input and output I would want to have while I can only currently support one at a time:

```
>>> [1,2,3]
    [1,2,3,4,5]
True

>>> ["a", "bc"]
    ["xy", "b", "bc"]
False

>>> [True, False, True]
>>> [False, True, False, True]
True

-- And even nested types
>>> [[1], [2,3]]
    [[2,4], [1], [2,3], [4]
True
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Give a couple of examples of what the user might enter as input and what type you want to interpret that input as.

Comment: good idea, I added them in

Comment: Can the user enter: `[ 1, 2, "cat" ]`?

Comment: yes but, that's not a valid Haskell list so the type system would reject it. (even if I had a polymorphic input function)

Comment: Actually `[1, 2, "cat"]` could be a legal Haskell list if there were a Num instance for String. I would get some clarification of what the point of the exercise is. Is it to see if you can write `sublist` correctly or is it to test your parser writing skills?

Comment: The exercise was to write `sublist` but now that I've done it I want to figure out a way for a polymorphic input without having to change `line 5` every time I want a different type of input. I don't know of a way to turn the inputs into lists.

Comment: There's no "polymorphic input" in Haskell. Not in the sense you want at any rate. A Haskell compiler or interpreter such as GHCi may see input like `[1,2,3]` and decide "hey, this looks like `Num a => [a]`, let's interpret it this way". But a regular three-line Haskell program is not a Haskell compiler, it has no type deduction machinery.

Comment: If you want to test `sublist` you can do this from GHCi prompt: `sublist [1,2,3] [4,5,6]` will work as well as `sublist ["1","2","3"] ["x","y","z"]`. If you want to do this in your own program, it would have to include a large chunk of GHC. There are ways to do this, but it's not a beginner's task.

Comment: “not a valid Haskell list so the type system would reject it” – there _is no type system_ at runtime since Haskell has full [type erasure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_erasure). You basically have to implement your own type system if it's supposed to do runtime polymorphism. A simple alternative type as in ErikR's answer is probably the most reasonable approach.

Answer (score 4):

`read` has to know in advance what kind of thing it is reading - that's just the way it works.

It is *not* the case that `read` looks at the string to determine what type to return. For instance consider:

```
read "1" :: Float
read "1" :: Int
```

The first read will return a Float (1.0) and the second an Int (1) even though the string being read is exactly the same.

You might think this is different from other languages, such as Python, where you can eval `"[1,2,3]"` and get a list and eval `"5"` to get a number and you don't have to tell eval what kind of thing to return. However, Haskell's answer to that is those languages are really only dealing with *one* type which is a sum type like:

```
data PyVal  = PyNum Int
            | PyStr String 
            | PyList [ PyVal ]
            | PyDict [ (PyStr, PyVal) ]
            | ...
```

Hence the universe of possible expressions is closed. So, actually, eval knows what kind of thing it is reading. In Haskell you can always add new types and therefore new reader and show functions.

Answer (score 2):

Your fundamental problem is Haskell-independent. Simply giving someone two string representations of values is not enough to determine equality. You have to tell that person what the interpretation of those values is supposed to be since one string can be interpreted many ways.

For example, let's say I give you the following inputs

```
>>> ['a', 'b']
    ['A', 'B']
```

What should you return? If I mean this to be interpreted using standard case-sensitive characters, then I should get back `False`. If on the other hand I'm using case-insensitive characters (e.g. as provided by [this package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/case-insensitive-1.2.0.6/docs/Data-CaseInsensitive.html)) then I should get back `True`. Just giving me the string representations is ambiguous.

If what you care about is the string representation itself, then just `read` your values into lists of strings and use `sublist` on those. If you do care about the interpretation of that string, then you have to either allow the user to specify that interpretation, or specify that interpretation in code somehow (of which @ErikR's ADT encoding and your type annotations are two possibilities).